# Не работает простой js-код

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые спецы по js, помогите! Имеем массив из нескольких элементов. Нужно чтобы js-код определял элементы со значением "1", а затем их индексы (номера). И выводил эти индексы! Код представлен ниже, но он не работает (выводятся сами элементы а не их индексы). Помогите правильно решить задачку.

```
<html>              
  <head><title>Этюд1</title></head>
  <body>
    <form>      
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Нажми" onclick="btnOnClick(vbt);"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      vbt = new Array(5,0,1,1,3,3);
      arr = new Array;
      x=0;
      function btnOnClick(){
        flag=0;
        while(arguments[flag]){
          for(i=0;i<arguments[flag].length;i++){
            if(String(arguments[flag][i]).substring(0,1)==1){
              arr[x]=arguments[flag][i];
              window.alert(arr[x]);
              x++;
            }
          }
          flag++;
        }
      }
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы перемудрили. Проще сделать так:

```
vbt = new Array(5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3);
arr = new Array;
x = 0;

function showIndices(args)
{    
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        if(args[i] == 1)        
            alert(i);            
}
```

или даже так:

```
function showIndices(args)
{  
    args.forEach(function(val, key) { if(val == 1) console.log(key); });   
}
```

А уже в обработчике нажатия вызывать функцию showIndices

Comment: я как понял, он хочет несколько аргументов

Comment: В моем массиве два элемента со значением 1. Нужно чтобы были найдены номера этих элементов (получается номера 2 и 3). Затем обязательно записаны в массив. А потом массив должен быть как-то выведен на экран, чтобы увидеть его содержимое (результаты.)

Comment: @ВасилийZadov так чем вас не устраивает предложенный вариант? Добавьте туда помимо вывода на экран еще и запись в массив, и, собственно, всё

Answer (score 0):

Я не спец по js но тут вроде и без второго массива можно обойтись, просто пробегаясь по исходному массиву, сравнивать его значение c нужным числом и при совпадении выводить индекс . Например if(array[i]==1){alert(i);} где i это текущий шаг цикла.`введите код здесь`
Может в задаче есть какие либо дополнительные условия, которые мешают сделать так?

Answer (score 0):

вы написали что-то странное, какие-то флаги и прочее, можно вот так.

```
var vbt = [5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3],
    arr = [];

function btnOnClick() {
  var args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //превратить arguments в массив;
    for (var i=0;i<args.length;i++) for (var n=0;n<args[i].length;n++) {
        if (String(args[i][n])==="1") {            
            console.log(i,n); //координаты здесь - i - номер аргумента, n индекс в массиве...
            arr.push([i,n]); //добавить координаты в arr
        }
    }
}
```

и не забывайте объявлять переменные, иначе они все будут глобальными.

Comment: Код почему-то не работает. В консоле ошибок пишет что функция btnOnClick() не определена.

Comment: запятых оставил лишних, пока чистил код от ненужного, поправил, вот [демо](http://jsbin.com/iYUFaLu/1/)

Comment: [такая организация arr](http://jsbin.com/iYUFaLu/3/) мне кажется более удобной

Comment: Но при нажатии кнопки по-прежнему ничего не выводится на экран!

Comment: Если вместо console.log написать window.alert то два раза выводит 0

Comment: И разве номер аргумента и индекс в массиве это не одно и то же????

Comment: нет, номер аргемента это номер аргумента, скажем если вы передали 
`btnOnClick(vbt,abt)` вы же зачем-то сделали перебор аргументов...

Comment: window.alert(i+','+n);